# how to change angular map marker color based on condition?

Tags: angular6

Made a syntax error and I am not able to understand where. Please check the following code.

```
<agm-marker *ngFor="let d of devices" [iconUrl]="'http://chart.apis.google.com/chartchst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=%E2%80%A2|'+ (d.status=='1')? '#008000' : '#ff0000'"
[latitude]="d.latitude" [longitude]="d.longitude">
</agm-marker>
```

Comment: Are you trying to achieve a URL that looks like this 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chartchst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=%E2%80%A2|#008000'? (For example)

Comment: I am just trying to change default red marker to green colour based on condition but it is coming black colour right now

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the color of the marker with passing in properties into the marker itself. (Check the 'label' props)

```
<agm-marker *ngFor="let d of devices" [iconUrl]="'http://chart.apis.google.com/chartchst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=%E2%80%A2'"
[latitude]="d.latitude" [longitude]="d.longitude"
[label]="{ color: (d.status=='1')? '#008000' : '#ff0000', // Label
fontWeight: 'bold', text: (i + 1).toString() }"
>
</agm-marker>
```

Comment: Not working, still location icon appears red colour only

Comment: Wat is difference between label property n iconurl property?

Comment: label property display with your marker or icon and iconUrl replace with marker.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it in the typescript file, where I selected which icon to use:

```
if (status === 'online' ) {
   this.markers[i].icon =  {
      url: '/assets/images/online.svg',
      scaledSize: {
         width: 30,
         height: 40
      }
   };
}
if (status === 'offline' ) {
   this.markers[i].icon =  {
      url: '/assets/images/offline.svg',
      scaledSize: {
         width: 30,
         height: 40
      }
    };
 }
```

Then I passed marker.icon as input to iconUrl as shown below:

```
<agm-marker  *ngFor="let marker of markers"
   [latitude] = "marker.lat"
   [longitude] = "marker.lon"
   [iconUrl] = "marker.icon"
   [title] = "marker.title"
><agm-marker>
```

This was a pragmatic way of solving it...